# Fixed Positioning not working in Safari 7

Tags: macos, safari, overlay, css-position

I'm having a problem on a website with Safari 7 (on OSX).
The website address is:
<Edit: Address not valid anymore. Sorry.>

If you click on vertical newsletter button, on the right edge of the content box, an overlay will pop-up.

This overlay looks good on most browser, but there is a problem with safari.

The overlay content is an absolutely positioned box of fixed width. It contains a div with the class "bg", which is a div with CSS position set to fixed and CSS top, right, bottom left set to 0.

The desired (and normally obtained) effect, is that this bg box sizes up to the width and height of the viewport. In safari, it just behaves as if it had it's position set to "absolute" - it just sizes up to the width and height of the container div.

Is this a known issue with Safari? Is there a bug filed? An update?

I could probably fix that by rewriting small parts of the HTML, CSS and JavaScript (if someone has an easier solution, you're welcome to share it!) but I'd like to understand what's happening at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on with that positioning thing, but here was my approach to get the same result across the browsers:

```
#overlays .overlay {  /* line 1081 */
    ...
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    ...
}

#overlays .overlay .content.text {  /* line 1185 */
    ...
    margin:0 auto;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Z-index but Z-index is not reliable with position:fixed, as shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mZMkE/2/ use translateZ transformation instead.

```
transform:translateZ(1px);
```

on your page elements.

EDIT: In your code, Add this css:

```
.bla, .projects, .contact  {
      -webkit-transform:translateZ(1px);
      -moz-transform:translateZ(1px);
      -o-transform:translateZ(1px);
      transform:translateZ(1px);
}
```

and then remove z-index refs from those elements and .intro.

Also You can try in other browsers as well

Comment: I don't think it's a stacking problem, but rather a problem with box sizing.